# Cake bake 2.1.3 appmodel not found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

When i try baking with console ..

```
cake bake model
```

After choosing which table name and settings.. i got this error

```
Baking model class for Shop...
Creating file c:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\Console\Model\Shop.php
Wrote `c:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\Console\Model\Shop.php`
Fatal error: Class 'AppModel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\lib\Cake\Model\CakeSchema.php on line 308
```

cake php version 2.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solve it.. my bad..

what i did was. directly execute `cake bake` from directory c:/location/apps/console

thus giving me the errors..

solution

need to add window environment variable `PATH` value `c:/location/apps/console`

browse with command prompt to c:/location/apps

then execute the `cake bake` from here

Comment: Maybe you could add some details to your own answer and accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you've migrated do you have a copy of AppModel.php in your app/Model directory. Same applies for AppHelper and AppController

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html

Comment: all files and class is present..it a fresh install of 2.1 i tried both from the website 2.1 and from github 2.1 branch .. still having the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is really the file AppModel.php in the app/Model folder (i accidentally deleted them). Then copy this file from a fresh cakephp-Version.